# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter #9 has not been set

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

hello I'm trying to execute mssql stored procedure from hibernate. Procedure has 8 input parameters and no output. But I get java.sql.SQLException: Parameter #9 has not been set whuli executing.

```
<sql-query name="insertMyData" callable="true">
        { ? = call InsertMyData(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) }
</sql-query>
```

Java invocation

```
Query query = m_entityManager.createNamedQuery("insertMyData");
        query.setParameter(1, transaction.getGuid());
        query.setParameter(2, new Date());
```

........ other parameters specified

Stored procedure

```
CREATE PROC dbo.insertMyData 
    @ID uniqueidentifier, 
    ...... 7 more parameters
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.TestData VALUES (
        @ID,
           ........ 7 more parameters

    )
END
```

Comment: Maybe remove the `? =` that you have before `call`?

Comment: nine `?` in your query ... nine parameters.

Comment: In this case I got NPE

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$Metadata.<init>(CustomLoader.java:544)
 at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:517)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1817)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad with my earlier suggestion:

According to https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=986612

Another person with the same issue, got it resolved by removing the "? =" since there was not 'return' defined for the quesry. I would suggest you try the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I suppose that first '?' is return value. But how can I illustrate it in code? Maybe I have to add smth to mapping file?

Comment: Are you calling executeUpdate on the 'Query' after you construct it? Can you put more code in your question.

Comment: Another thing you could try is remove the "? =" and also replace all the ?,... with names parameters. Its better that way anyway. It would look something like - call InsertMyData(:uniqueidentifier, :param2, ....) and in your code use .setParameter("uniqueidentifier", transaction.getGuid()). Also make sure you are calling executeUpdate and not list.

Comment: i was calling via query.getResultList()

Comment: I did it in way you proposed but I get this now 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: callable not yet supported for native queries
 at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:171)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1190)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:357)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have ignored the first `?` and called `setParameter` only 8 times for the `?` inside the procedure call.

This is how you should set your first parameter:

```
statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR); //Assuming statement is your CallableStatement and return type of procedure is Varchar
```

Comment: What should I set for this first parameter? (it is @return_value I suppose)

Comment: Updated answer with your above question